# How to implement embedded loops in ATS?

Tags: ats

For instance, how can I implement something in ATS corresponding the following code in C:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
{
  for (j = 0; j < i; j += 1) do_something(i, j);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a combinator-based solution:

```
val () = (N).foreach()(lam i => (i).foreach()(lam j => do_something(i, j)))
```

Please try the code on-line:

Compiling to C:
https://glot.io/snippets/ejogc7ugs8

Compiling to JavaScript:
http://www.ats-lang.org/SERVER/MYCODE/Patsoptaas_serve.php?mycode_url=http://pastebin.com/raw/t16FVqmB

Answer (score 1):

Here's a directly translated, loop-based approach:

```
for (i := 0; i < N; i := i + 1)
begin
    for (j := 0; j < i; j := j + 1)
    begin
        do_something (i, j);
    end;
end
```

See [this snippet](https://glot.io/snippets/ejoswod8tw) for a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

For using `for*`, one needs to explicitly annotate invariants for both loops:

```
implement
main0 () = let
    var i: int? // = 0
    var j: int? // = 0
in
    for* (i: int): (i: int) => (i := 0; i < N; i := i + 1)
    begin
        for* (j: int): (j: int) => (j := 0; j < i; j := j + 1)
        begin
            do_something (i, j)
        end
    end
end
```

This is for enthusiasts of for-loops :)

Comment: What would you say is the correct termination metric for the inner loop? For the outer, that's `N - i`, that seems simple enough.

Comment: Using for* always makes me nervous. Here is a working version: https://glot.io/snippets/ejq5yucxj6